# liferay error on superclassing IFramePortlet

Tags: iframe, liferay

In the developing of liferay portlet, If I use `IFramePortlet(com.liferay.portlet.iframe.IFramePortlet)` in portlet-class tag in portlet xml

ERROR like this -

```
Registering portlets for gospel-for-asia-portlet

06:08:00,712 
ERROR [localhost-startStop-6][PortletBagFactory:411] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portlet.iframe.IFramePortlet
(sometimes NoClassDefFoundError happens)
```

This error occurs on registering not building. I did `add External Jars` with `portal-impl.jar` for this.

That source is presented on github. I didn't change anything.

I am struggling with this problem for couple of days. Any clues would be welcomed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You *must not* add `portal-impl.jar` to your custom portlets. This is the problem: `IFramePortlet` is part of `portal-impl.jar`, so it's part of Liferay's implementation. You don't have access to this class from a plugin. If you want it, you'll have to get the sourcecode and implement it yourself.

Adding `portal-impl.jar` will try to initialize all kind of portal infrastructure for a second time. Plus, you'll not want to depend on such a big library just for a tiny trivial portlet implementation.

Comment: Yes, Your opinion must be true.  
Implementation myself must be best way.  
But indeed I am just beginner.  
Moreover I don't understand yet why it can be problem that I just use already-done implementation. As you know, Reuse and inheritance is the virtue of OOP. 
  
I use com.liferay.portlet.iframe.util in portlet-impl.jar without problem. But once I change portlet-class in portlet.xml to com.liferay.portlet.iframe.IFramePortlet, It starts to pour out the Error.
But Out-of-box iframe source has no problem.
  
I believe experts like you must know the reason and the way.

Comment: The problem with portal-impl.jar is not in the single class, it's in the 29M additional code that comes with initialization procedured (spring) that are not supposed to run twice per appserver. I don't care about the reason why using the class won't work when it's wrong to add the dependency in the first place. Copy the class if you need it - problem solved.

Comment: I see. I really thank you for your help. but actually I copied the classes including IFramePortlet, but they have dependancy with other files, I added and added related files and finally give up. @.@

Comment: Well, sometimes you'll just have to stop copying. Keep in mind that Liferay, as a platform, must come with maximum flexibility - e.g. everything *must* be configurable. In contrast, if you implement for your own usecase, you can get away with a lot less flexibility, more simplicity, thus better maintainability. I'm assuming that a simple IFrame portlet doesn't take more than an hour to write (and that's already *a lot*). Add some tweaks and extras in another hour. But if you want the most generic IFrame ever, you'll have something to do.

Comment: anyway, We are implementing auto login with portlet configuration values.as we find it out, IFramePortlet calls proxy.jsp. and it pass login info to the iframe.
Now we implement the function ourself without no shortcut.